# Same steps for multiple named environments with GitLab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Is there a way to configure multiple specifically-named environments (specifically, `test`, `stage`, and `prod`)?

In their documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html) they talk about dynamically-created environments, but they are all commit based.

My build steps are the same for all of them, save for swapping out the slug:

```
deploy_to_test:
    environment:
         name: test
         url: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.mydomain.com
    scripts:
         - deploy ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}

deploy_to_stage:
    environment:
         name: stage
         url: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.mydomain.com
    scripts:
         - deploy ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}

 deploy_to_prod:
    environment:
         name: prod
         url: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.mydomain.com
    scripts:
         - deploy ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
```

Is there any way to compress this down into one set of instructions? Something like:

```
deploy:
    environment:
         url: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.mydomain.com
    scripts:
         - deploy ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you can use [**anchors**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#anchors). If I follow the documentation properly, you would rewrite it using a hidden key `.XX` and then apply it with `<<: *X`.

For example this to define the key:

```
.job_template: &deploy_definition
    environment:
         url: ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}.mydomain.com
    scripts:
         - deploy ${CI_ENVIRONMENT_SLUG}
```

And then all blocks can be writen using `<<: *job_template`. I assume `environment` will merge the name with the predefined URL.

```
deploy_to_test:
   <<: *deploy_definition
    environment:
         name: test

deploy_to_stage:
   <<: *deploy_definition
    environment:
         name: stage

 deploy_to_prod:
   <<: *deploy_definition
    environment:
         name: prod
```

---

Full docs section from the link above:

> YAML has a handy feature called 'anchors', which lets you easily duplicate content across your document. Anchors can be used to duplicate/inherit properties, and is a perfect example to be used with hidden keys to provide templates for your jobs.
>
> The following example uses anchors and map merging. It will create two jobs, test1 and test2, that will inherit the parameters of .job_template, each having their own custom script defined:
>
> ```
> .job_template: &job_definition  # Hidden key that defines an anchor named 'job_definition'
>   image: ruby:2.1
>   services:
>     - postgres
>     - redis
>
> test1:
>   <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
>   script:
>     - test1 project
>
> test2:
>   <<: *job_definition           # Merge the contents of the 'job_definition' alias
>   script:
>     - test2 project
> ```
>
> & sets up the name of the anchor (job_definition), << means "merge the given hash into the current one", and * includes the named anchor (job_definition again). The expanded version looks like this:
>
> ```
> .job_template:
>   image: ruby:2.1
>   services:
>     - postgres
>     - redis
>
> test1:
>   image: ruby:2.1
>   services:
>     - postgres
>     - redis
>   script:
>     - test1 project
>
> test2:
>   image: ruby:2.1
>   services:
>     - postgres
>     - redis
>   script:
>     - test2 project
> ```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Comment: Can you comment/compare with @Fliss Hou's solution?

Comment: This is still extremely tedious when one has lots of jobs. Is there really no better way to do this?

Comment: Actually the answer by https://stackoverflow.com/a/69203682/1447953 seems very promising. Seems to work in my short test.

Answer (score 17):

Besides what the answer offered, I'd like to add another similar way to achieve kind of the same thing but it's more flexible rather than to use a template and then merge it in a stage.

What you can do is to create a hidden key as well, but in this format, e.g.,

```
.login: &login |
  cmd1
  cmd2
  cmd3
  ...
```

And then you can apply it to different stages by using the '*', the asterisk, like:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ...
    - *login
    - ...

bake:
  stage: bake
  script:
    - ...
    - *login
    - ...
```

And the result would be equivalent to:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - ...
    - cmd1
    - cmd2
    - cmd3
    - ...

bake:
  stage: bake
  script:
    - ...
    - cmd1
    - cmd2
    - cmd3
    - ...
```

> Based on the resource of:
>   https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19677#note_13008199

As for the template implementation, it's "merged". With my own experience, if you append more scripts after merging a template, the template scripts will be overwritten. And you cannot apply multiple templates at a time. Only the last template scripts will be executed. For example:

```
.tmp1: &tmp1
  script:
    - a
    - b

.tmp2: &tmp2
  script:
    - c
    - d

job1:
  <<: *tmp1
  <<: *tmp2
  stage: xxx

job2:
  <<: *tmp2
  stage: yyy
  script:
    - e
    - f
```

The equivalent result would be:

```
job1:
  stage: xxx
  script:
    - c
    - d

job2:
  stage: yyy
  script:
    - e
    - f
```

If not sure about the syntax correctness, just copy and paste your `.gitlab.yml` file content to "CI Lint" to validate. The button is in the tab of Pipelines.

[gitlab](/questions/tagged/gitlab) [gitlab-ci](/questions/tagged/gitlab-ci) [yaml](/questions/tagged/yaml)

Comment: what is the name of syntax `|`? and any documents for it?

Comment: @LeiYang It seems like the `|` means multiline in YAML. However, I don't actually see any formal documentation mentions this usage. See [Issue 19677](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/19677) for more information.

Answer (score 11):

Just in case: Gitlab offers (since 11.3) an *extends* keyword, which can be used to "templates" yaml entries (so far as I understand it):

See the [official doc](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#extends)

Comment: Much clearer and intuitive solution than the accepted one. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried implementing variables for various environments and using different jobs for various environments? I've come up with a solution for you.

```
image: node:latest
variables:
  GIT_DEPTH: '0' 

stages:
  - build
  - deploy

workflow:
    rules:
      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME ==  "develop"
        variables:
          DEVELOP: "true"
          ENVIRONMENT_NAME: Develop
          WEBSITE_URL: DEVELOP_WEBSITE_URL
          S3_BUCKET: (develop-s3-bucket-name)
          AWS_REGION: ************** develop
          AWS_ACCOUNT: ********develop

      - if: $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME == "main" 
        variables:                                 
          PRODUCTION:  "true"
          ENVIRONMENT_NAME: PRODUCTION
          WEBSITE_URL: $PROD_WEBSITE_URL
          S3_BUCKET: $PROD-S3-BUCKET-NAME
          AWS_REGION: ************** (prod-region)
          AWS_ACCOUNT: ***********(prod-acct)
      - when: always 

build-app:
  stage: build
  script:
     #build-script
  environment: 
    name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME

deploy-app:
  stage: deploy
  script:
     #deploy-script
  environment: 
    name: $ENVIRONMENT_NAME
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).